# Update multiple records with differing where and set values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a statement that will update multiple records into a table in a single `SQL` statement.
I know there is multiple SO threads and other web sites addressing this batch `Insert` statements, but I can't find one that I can understand enough for me to manipulate the statement to work for me.

The single `Update` statement is simple enough

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ShiftTimes]
SET SubSection = 'One'
WHERE ID = '9E3C491A-3FE1-47F1-B701-000009C08CD0'
```

And to illustrate what I am trying to do (With incorrect syntax)

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ShiftTimes]
SET SubSection = 'One', 'Two', 'Three'
WHERE ID = '9E3C491A-3FE1-47F1-B701-000009C08CD0', '10F9F862-4723-4105-A8E9-000017097EBE', '25810E61-8E86-432B-9387-00003048E74D'
```

So basically I am trying to do this, in one statement

```
Where ID = '9E3C491A-3FE1-47F1-B701-000009C08CD0' Then set SubSection = 'One'
Where ID = '10F9F862-4723-4105-A8E9-000017097EBE' Then set SubSection = 'Two'
Where ID = '25810E61-8E86-432B-9387-00003048E74D' Then set SubSection = 'Three'
```

I thought I could do something like what is in this thread [SQL Insert Into with Inner Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469503/sql-insert-into-with-inner-join/44469617), but again, I can't see how I would be able to apply it to my situation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I apologize if this changes the question too much, but I am trying to update anywhere from 50,000 to 100,000 records and I am trying to optimize the code to `Update` faster then looping over a single query and updating that way.

Comment: So, is this update or insert?

Comment: @T.S. An `Update`

Comment: @T.S. Sorry edited the question.

Comment: Is this just an exercise? I really don't see the reason for making a complex query unless you need to update `N` number of rows in a loop using dynamic SQL. If that is not the case why not just run 3 statements?

Comment: @T.S. This is just a small example of what I need to show what I am doing. In reality I will need to update anywhere from 50,000 to 100,000 records and running line by line is just so slow.

Comment: If `WHERE ID = '9E3C491A-3FE1-47F1-B701-000009C08CD0'` affect many records, I really don't see how you will gain much by running single statement. You will still have search performed on table

Comment: @T.S Not if ID is the primary key, this ensures only one record will be affected.

Comment: I guess, the question then, how you are going to identify, which id is shift "one", "two", or "three"

Comment: @T.S.  Absolutely correct, but that issue is also sorted out. I just needed a way to optimise the update statement to make it faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to update many rows, I suggest inserting the new values into a temp table together with the ID and then use it as source for the update statement.
These are 3 statements.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    ID CHAR(36),            -- Choose the same types as in the ShiftTimes table
    NewValue VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #temp
  (ID, NewValue)
VALUES
  ('9E3C491A-3FE1-47F1-B701-000009C08CD0', 'One'),
  ('10F9F862-4723-4105-A8E9-000017097EBE', 'Two'),
  ('25810E61-8E86-432B-9387-00003048E74D', 'Three')

UPDATE
    [dbo].[ShiftTimes]
SET
    ShiftTimes.SubSection = T.NewValue
FROM
    [dbo].[ShiftTimes] S
    INNER JOIN #temp T
        ON S.ID = T.ID;
```

The second statement is the big one with > 50,000 rows and each Id/value-pair appears only once.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the code. Got it working, but it will only take 60 pairs of data (ID, NewValue) ie, only update 60 records at a time. Is there a workaround for this? Or is that the max SQL can handle?

Comment: According to [Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), the limit is 1000 rows. Don't know why you hit a limit at 60. You will have to insert in batches.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ShiftTimes]
SET
    SubSection = CASE ID WHEN '9E3C491A-3FE1-47F1-B701-000009C08CD0' THEN 'One'
                         WHEN '10F9F862-4723-4105-A8E9-000017097EBE' THEN 'Two'
                         WHEN '25810E61-8E86-432B-9387-00003048E74D' THEN 'Three' END
WHERE
    ID IN ('9E3C491A-3FE1-47F1-B701-000009C08CD0',
           '10F9F862-4723-4105-A8E9-000017097EBE',
           '25810E61-8E86-432B-9387-00003048E74D');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can maximize the use of `table value constructor` available in **sql server 2008** and higher versions. It will be easier considering you have multiple values.

```
update [dbo].[ShiftTimes] 
set SubSection  = t2.SubSection
from 
(values ('9E3C491A-3FE1-47F1-B701-000009C08CD0','One')
        , ('10F9F862-4723-4105-A8E9-000017097EBE','Two')
        , ('25810E61-8E86-432B-9387-00003048E74D','Three'))  
       AS t2 (ID, SubSection) 
where t2.ID = ID
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but, I am getting ambiguous name for `ID`. Looks like the compiler is showing it as `VARCHAR` instead of a `uniqueidentifier`. How do I get around this?

Comment: @KyloRen, you can change tvc columns as `(IDt, Subsection)`, then `t2.IDt = ID`.